# Should "move to serverfault" need more votes if the OP votes for it?

Tags: discussion, migration

If the OP thinks a question should be moved, is that enough reason to move it?

Looking at the answers, it might be a better idea to allow the OP + one other vote to move. I suspect that most of the cases where the OP asks to have a question moved would be for the better because it indicates they now have a better idea of what each site is for or of what kind of question they are asking.

Answer (score 10):

It has been demonstrated repeatedly in the past that the OP is not the best judge of where their question belongs (which is why we have a migration mechanism in the first place).

I would actually be more likely to say that the OP should be completely barred from voting on their own topic in both closing and reopening. If they want it closed, they should flag it for moderator attention.

Comment: Well said. I would rather deal with it. In various cases we have seen questions moved that should never have moved, or moved to the wrong site and we end up playing ping-pong with the question.

Answer (score 3):

I'd see more of a case for if the OP votes to close it as a duplicate - Given the search is "less than brilliant", and others may come along and identify the dupe, it allows them to stick their hands up, plead guilty and speed up the process; albeit currently by a single vote.

With "move to [other site]", it may be the case that the OP doesn't know about/read any of Jeff/Joels blogs/tweets. Could the "Ask Question" page be reformatted to better highlight the other sites - to me, I'd subconsciously discounted the right hand side bar as advertising space, and applied the appropriate amount of attention to it.